# Hibernate - No Suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//*

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to run hibernate in a Java project that is referenced by a web project. Simple enough except that I can't get hibernate to connect to my database. I have a lot of people describing this problem and getting tons of answers however none seem to work for me.

This is how my **hibernate.cfg.xml** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/dbname</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">commander</property>

     <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">50</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Enable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping resource="com/amakena/profile/mapping/Credentials.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/amakena/profile/mapping/Profile.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/amakena/profile/mapping/City.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/amakena/profile/mapping/Country.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/amakena/profile/mapping/Gender.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I debugged the code to **DriverManagerConnectionProvider** class, the exception is thrown attempting the **getConnection()** method

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProps);
```

I checked the url and connectionProps and they are the ones in hibernate.cfg.xml

I have added *mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin* in my tomcat \lib folder and I can see it in eclipse under Libraries>Apache Tomcat v6.0>. I also added it to my %Javahome%\lib\ext and my CLASSPATH variable (which I know is useless by I am kindda desperate).

I made sure my driver is installed properly by running the following code just before the **session.beginTransaction()** which in turn leads to **DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection()**

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.put("user", "root");
connectionProperties.put("password", "root");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", connectionProperties);
```

I noticed that emitting the first line causes the same exception.

Exception thrown

```
WARNING: Method execution failed: 
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at     org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
at $Proxy0.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
at com.amakena.profile.dao.CredentialsDao.hydrate(CredentialsDao.java:45)
at com.amakena.profile.ProfileManager.login(ProfileManager.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/dbname
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
... 37 more
WARNING: --Erroring: batchId[24] message[org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection]
```

I appreciate all the help I could get. Thanks in advance.

Versions Used: Tomcat v6.0 - Hibernate 3.6.6 - Java 6 - Eclipse 3.5.2 R35x

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot the colon after "mysql":

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname</property>
```

Here's the [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for the URL format:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database]
```

*No suitable driver* always means that the driver JAR was loaded, but your URL syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Not always. The driver could just not be loaded at all, or the ClassNotFoundException was totally suppressed. But this is indeed not the case when the driver loading job is delegated to a bit decent ORM.

Comment: Why would it be suppressed?  And is that the case with Hibernate?  Wouldn't driver not loaded be indicated by ClassNotFoundException?   That's always been my experience.

Comment: Suppressed by a beginner's mistake of not handling the exception at all on the `Class#forName()` call.

Answer (score 5):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

You are missing the *:* after *mysql*

Comment: Thank you, you are right on. I wanted to up the result but it's my first time on stackoverflow and I don't have the enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason is that the driver class is not found, make sure your driver class is successfully loaded.