# Jboss mysql - No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb

I get following error using hibernate:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
```

The problem is similar to: [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969970/hibernate-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql) but I think my url is right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

i found the solution searching here on stackoferflow :)

I needed to place my mysql-connector jar file into jboss/server/default/lib.
Although I dont understand it since i added this jar file as a dependency and it was placed in the lib folder on deployment.