# JBoss 7.1: No suitable driver found java:mysql - could not open connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss7.x

I was looking for an answer but didn't find solution.
I'm developing simple web-app using JSF2 and Hibernate. This is first time I'm using Hibernate and I'm facing many problems with configuration. My current issue is:
I configured mysql connector as a module in JBoss7.1 modules. Then I created datasource and added mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar to the classpath (It is in WEB-INF/lib directory in .war). After starting JBoss I'm getting following logs:

```
23:44:07,497 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
23:44:07,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
...
23:44:20,348 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
23:44:21,532 INFO  
...
[org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb]
23:44:21,535 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root}
23:44:21,556 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
```

And then application is deployed and server starts successfully. When I try to invoke method trying to persist some data I obtain

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
and
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
```

I'm sure the mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar is in the WEB-INF/lib directory in war file. Any ideas what am I missing here? MySQL server wersion is 5.1.63, but I don't think it is relevant here. 
Thank's a lot in advance!

edit:
Port is OK, I checked everything two times;-) BUT, now I'm really confused, because code is working well outside the container. I created class which uses the same code (HIbernateUtil to obtain session factory) and there are no exceptions, and data is inserted to DB. Could you please explain me why it is working in that way, and why it is not working under the container? And how to fix this, because I have no idea... Thank you very much!

My standalone.xml file:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testDS" pool-name="testDS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
            <show-model value="true"/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
            <properties>
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                    1
                </property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

    <deployments>
        <deployment name="jboss-as-helloworld-jsf.war" runtime-name="jboss-as-helloworld-jsf.war">
            <content sha1="87e5656e4c0b15f7864df9e68328d290999a1144"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
</server>
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.3, I had to add Hibernate jars as external jars to build path, even after changes in modules/org/hibernate/main (I changed module.xml and replaced old jars). After that changes I got different exception during deploy: .org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found In Jboss's logs there is mentioned that com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is deployed. HELP!

Comment: may be this helps https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7?_sscc=t

Comment: Thanks, I read it before posting here - no solution there. I also read documentation which is mentioned in your link, but still no clue what is wrong.

Comment: Is it working without the container? Test in a main class? Is mysql running on the default port, since you did not specified it?

Comment: Port is OK, I checked everything two times;-) BUT, now I'm really confused, because code is working well outside the container. I created class which uses the same code (HIbernateUtil to obtain session factory) and there are no exceptions, and data is inserted to DB. Could you please explain me why it is working in that way, and why it is not working under the container? And how to fix this, because I have no idea... Thank you very much!

Comment: Your `standalone.xml` looks correct. What Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Hibernate 4.1.3, I had to add Hibernate jars as external jars to build path, even after changes in modules/org/hibernate/main (I changed module.xml and replaced old jars). After that changes I got different exception during deploy:

.org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class not found

In Jboss's logs there is mentioned that com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is deployed. HELP!

Answer (score 7):

If anybody is facing a similar problem, here is a solution:

- check stuff people mentioned under my question here;
- if this do not work, check if hibernate libraries are from the same bundle (the newest is 4.1.3, JBoss 7.1.1 has 4.0.1);
- make sure you do not duplicate connector and hibernate libraries in class-path and Manifest.mf dependencies (that was cause of my issue)

Thanks to everyone who replied here, you were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
Step 1:

You create one folder in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com

 create mysql folder>>

 create main folder>>

 create module.xml file>>

 put mysql connector jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin)


Step 2:

 add line on this location jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\hibernate\main\module

  <module name="com.mysql"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems jboss is using hibernate from its own module which does not have the visibility to see com.mysql driver.

First configured mysql connector as a module in JBoss7.1 modules

Then you need to added dependency in hibernate module provided by JBOSS

Path for module.xml should be `${JBOSS_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main`

```
<!-- Represents the Hibernate 4.0.x module-->
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="4" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.envers" services="import" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
        
        <module name="com.mysql"/>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score -1):

Place the jdbc sql in the library folder: jboss/server/default/lib

[Jboss mysql - No suitable driver found for jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418625/jboss-mysql-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc)

Comment: There is no such a folder in JBoss 7. Instead I tried to put the library under standalone/lib and standalone/deployments (that is equal to install driver as a deployment) - both are not working.

Answer (score -1):

Normally your jboss configuration should have a lib folder in which you can put your jdbc driver:

> 8.2.2. Installing the JDBC Driver and Deploying the DataSource
>
> To make the JDBC driver classes available to JBoss, copy the file
>   mysql-connector-java-3.0.15-ga-bin.jar from the Connector/J
>   distribution to the lib directory in the default server configuration
>   (assuming that is the configuration you’re running, of course). Then
>   create a file in the deploy directory called mysql-ds.xml with the
>   following datasource configuration. The database user name and
>   password corresponds the MySql user we created in the previous
>   section.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/db.html

If it doesn't work, you can still put the driver in lib/ext/ folder of your jdk, but it's not the appropriate usage.

Comment: Your quote is from the document 'Getting Started with JBoss 4.0'. This question is about JBoss 7.1. The two are very different indeed (JBoss 7 doesn't have the concept of servers), and this advice does not apply.